# Помощь в построении архитектурной логики Ethereum приложения

Tags: python, веб-программирование, архитектура, blockchain, ethereum

Хочу сделать приложение на блокчейне (Ethereum). Но слишком остро встал вопрос построения архитектуры.

По моей задумке в вебе будет сайт с личным кабинетом и другими плюшками, откуда будут происходить разного рода операции (прим. Покупка/Продажа) с непосредственно самой сетью блокчейна. 
А так же мобильное приложение. Ну и само собой нужно продумать еще как-то возможность расширения проекта.

Стек, который я использую - Python/Django/Golang(бекенд), возможно еще JS если без него не обойтись, Solidity (для смарт-контрактов)

Как я это все вижу?
В любом случае нужен централизованный сервер и БД для учета юзеров и всех их данных, а уже с него выполнять запросы к сети Эфира?
Тогда от такая архитектура сведет на нет всю фишку децентрализации :(

Хотелось бы услышать мнение экспертов, т.к я реального опыта не имел и сейчас лишь вникаю в эту фишку.

В общем нужен веб-проект, который будет работать с блокчейном на Ethereum .

Comment: Юзерами могут быть адреса в сети Ethereum. Их пароль - приватный ключ, которыми они подписывают транзакции. Данные можно хранить в смарт контракте. Юзеры могут отправлять транзакции прямо с вашего приложения, при этом подписывая их при помощи плагина metamask. Ваща задача - сделать удобный интерфейс, и сами смарт контракты.

Comment: @Zergatul спасибо большое, прояснилось многое!)